# Array in dictionary doesn't want to have assigned a value

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim strarrayvars As New Dictionary(Of String, String())
strarrayvars.Add("Item", {})
ReDim strarrayvars("Item")(0 To 1)
Dim str As String = "abc"
strarrayvars.Item("Item")(1) = str
```

Value in array does not assign. After this assignment strarrayvars("item")(1) is still null.

How to assign the value correctly?

Picture from debugger: [image: debugger]

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use `List(Of T)`.

Comment: @SLaks List instead of Dictionary?

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  [Show an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: "item", array index and str are generated while application is running. But I checked those in debugger and they have valid values.

Comment: Put the breakpoint **AFTER** that line and then check the contents of `strarrayvars` ...

Comment: Actually this breakpoint is being hit for 3rd time at the moment of taking picture. That's why you can see three `Nothing` values in `strarrayvars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try creating and dimensioning the array and then put it in the dictionary?

Comment: Oh, that's right. Everytime when I call ReDim it erases my array. That was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many items you have in the string() but if it is fixed at 2 then this should work

```
    Dim strarrayvars As New Dictionary(Of String, String())
    strarrayvars.Add("Item", New String() {"", ""})

    Dim str As String = "abc"
    strarrayvars.Item("Item")(1) = str
```

depending on your usage the string() could be replaced with a List as has been mentioned.

Comment: ReDim was causing problems, it was mentioned in comments below prev answer.

Comment: If the OP only had two values then there wasn't a need for the ReDim.

Comment: I was doing this in a loop